# debugging mongodb queries and other functions in php

Tags: php, debugging, logging, mongodb

How do you go about debugging your php mongodb code?
For example, if I execute a :

```
$cursor = $this->Collection->find($myQueryCriteria);
```

If it works, I get back data in $cursor.  If it does not work, I get back an empty array().

Is there some way to see what happened?  Maybe some kind of logging can be turned on for mongodb to log errors or analysis of queries and other commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way to see what happened?

To "see what happened", use the [explain function](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.explain.php) on the cursor.

This will provide an indication of the index used, the number of documents scanned, etc. Details on the explain plan [output here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain).

> Maybe some kind of logging can be turned on for mongodb to log errors or analysis of queries and other commands?

For logging actual DB queries, use the [DB profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler). By default, "slow" queries are logged to the DB logs (queries > 100ms), but the profiler does give you better control of this.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be short and not too kind: no. You can switch on profiling but that only helps to see what queries arrived to the server. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler level 2 logs all operations.

Also check http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.lasterror.php

Comment: Well... if `MongoDB::lastError()` exists, why the answer is `no`?

Comment: because "some kind of logging can be turned on for mongodb to log errors or analysis of queries and other commands" -- there is no such thing. Sometimes I wish too there was something -- like N documents matched criteria X , M documents matched criteria X and Y etc.